# R returning number instead of string

Tags: r

Why does `c(...)` returns a number instead of the string in the example below?

```
> Location$NamePrint
[1] Burundi
273 Levels: Afghanistan Africa ...

> ParentLocation$NamePrint
[1] Eastern Africa
273 Levels: Afghanistan Africa ...

> c(Location$NamePrint, ParentLocation$NamePrint)
[1] 36 71
```

These numbers are the position of the strings in the levels?

My goal is to create a vector with these two elements (their string value), using `c(Location$NamePrint, ParentLocation$NamePrint)`

Comment: use `as.character` like this `c(as.character(Location$NamePrint), as.character(ParentLocation$NamePrint))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's a `factor`. For example:

```
x <- as.factor("a")
c(x)

# [1] 1
```

To resolve this, we can treat `x` `as.character`:

```
x <- as.character("a")
c(x)

# [1] "a"
```

As @joran mentions, there's a handy function in `forcats` for this as well, `forcats::fct_c()`.

See `?c` and read the details section for additional information:

> Note that factors are treated only via their internal integer codes; one proposal has been to use:

```
x <- as.factor("a")
y <- as.factor("b")

c.factor <- function(..., recursive=TRUE) unlist(list(...), recursive=recursive)

c.factor(x, y)

# [1] a b
# Levels: a b
```

Comment: Options: round trip from character back to factor or use the handy `forcats::fct_c()` function.

Comment: Nice, I've included this option in the answer

Answer (score 2):

The [structure](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.3/topics/str) (`str()`) of your objects will reveal that they are factors.

```
demo1 <- as.factor("Burundi")
demo2 <- as.factor("Eastern Africa")
str(demo1)
```

See:

```
> str(demo1)
 Factor w/ 1 level "Burundi": 1
```

So when you concatenate them, this happens:

```
> c(demo1, demo2)
[1] 1 1
```

If you want to bring them in to a vector with their text, use `as.character`:

```
> c(as.character(demo1), as.character(demo2))
[1] "Burundi"        "Eastern Africa"
```

Or even better, do this to the original vectors, e.g.:

```
demo1 <- as.character(demo1)
```